# Convert the date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```
cookie_id       date1     date2
201515207920    080515  2015-08-05
203867695306    072015  2015-07-20
```

How do I convert the date1 to date2 format (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Can't run it....  notice,  My syntax is running at netezze warehouse.

```
select str_to_date(date1, '%M%d%y')
from abc
```

> 18:05:41  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1100, SQL
>   State: HY000]  ERROR:  Function 'STR_TO_DATE(VARCHAR, UNKNOWN)' does
>   not exist     Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given
>   argument types    You may need to add explicit typecasts ... 1
>   statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000
>   sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Comment: hi vkp, database is mysql

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
select str_to_date(date1, '%m%d%y')
```

However, you are at the whims of MySQL for converting two digit years to four digit years.  You might want to incorporate the right century into the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
date('Y-m-d');
```